# How to hide object without his geo-node attributes

Tags: rendering, modifiers, geometry-nodes, masking, shadowcatcher

I have some issues with ray visibility. I added growing grass geo-nodes to the Cube, and want to hide cube with shadow catcher mask. But by that grass is also hides. So how can i hide the cube without hiding geo-node based grass?

Comment: Could you use a *Single Vertex* instead of a *Cube* to carry the *GeometryNodes* modifier ? As a point, it is not rendered.

Comment: @StefLAncien A cube would also not be rendered if you do not connect it with the _Group Output_. But in this case it should function as a shadow catcher (I guess), so a single vertex would not make sense as it would not catch any shadow... but still make everything invisible generated by the nodetree (and you cannot distribute grass on it). As I understood the question, the cube should not only be invisible, but show shadows. But even if not, as I said simply not connecting it to the GN output makes it invisible.

Answer (score 1):

The good thing with *Geometry Nodes* is, you can reference objects in the nodetree but they do not have to be visible in viewport or render.

So, to use a shadow catcher object to distribute grass and have the grass still be visible, just add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier to a different object and reference the shadow catcher with an *Object Info* node.

Like in the following example: I have a plane that is a shadow catcher. Then I have a cube with *Geometry Nodes*. I have an *Object Info* node referencing the plane and I am distributing points on it (then move them slightly upwards so that they are not inside the plane). I instance icospheres on those points, the icospheres are visible and the plane is invisible, just catching the shadows of the spheres.

[image: gn with shadow catcher]

If you simply do not want to **see** the cube in the render, then you just do not connect it to the *Group Output* of your *Geometry Nodes* nodetree...